# Which SAT solver has the ability to pause and resume?

Tags: optimization, sat

When running some instances, it may take a while and I would like to switch between my desktop PCs in order not to fry them.

Thus, having a feature to pause and resume long running solvers would be helpful.

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, also how is TSP involved?

Comment: TSP is involved because it is NP-complete.  :-)
Anyway, necessary or not is immaterial.  I would like to know if there are any.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't know of any with a built-in pauze function, but maybe it exists and I just never found that option. It shouldn't be too hard to add I suppose. Or you could cheat and use a virtual machine which you can pauze.

Comment: I don't have the luxury of a vm, though.

Comment: Why is it luxus? What's so hard about creating one VM for this task? Also [read this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/minisat/Swky3GWtnbs) (especially the last comment from the developer of cryptominisat)

Comment: I'm just a hobbyist.  There's so much I have to learn.  Plus, I can't afford a vm ( no idea whether it's free or not )

Comment: There are free ones, and they will be good enough (they may lack advanced features such as live migration)

Comment: @harold which free ones do you recommend?